# Как работать со вложенными JSON объектами postgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Занимаюсь тем, что переписываю свою базу с `SQL` на `PostreSQL`. Имею вот такой синтаксис:

`SELECT JSON_VALUE(wr.jsonDetails, '$.risk.score') FROM WalletRisks wr;`

И это работает, я получаю значения поля `score`:

```
50
50
50
50
```

Как мне написать этот же запрос, но на PostreSQL? Единственное, что у меня пока получилось это:

`select WalletRisks.jsonDetails ->> 'risk' from WalletRisks;`

И как результат:

```
{"level":2,"score":50,"verdict_time":1610803292}
{"level":2,"score":50,"verdict_time":1609775813}
{"score":50,"verdict_time":1623061355,"level":2}
{"level":2,"score":50,"verdict_time":1608741456}
```

Дело в том, что это получается вложенный объект, и мне надо получить доступ к полю объекта внутри другого объекта. Как мне это сделать на `PostgreSQL`?

Answer (score 0):

`select WalletRisks.jsonDetails -> 'risk' ->> 'score' from WalletRisks;`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]